# 'IEnumerable<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<object>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm writing Api with Visual Studio, but I get errors.

Error 1:
[image: error 1]

Error 2: 
[image: error 2]

```
Login login = new Login();
//set some properties
db.Logins.Add(login);
db.SaveChanges();
```

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And:

```
var user = db.Logins.Where(x => x.UserName == username && 
                                x.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();
```

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UserName' and no extension method 'UserName' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help me.

Comment: Can you post the code of the `db`? Is it a DbContext? Please right-click `go to definition` at `Logins` and show us that code as well.

Comment: I think db.Logins is not a `DbSet<Login>`. If it was it would work, so please show the code of `db` as well.

Answer (score 1):

**IEnumerable** is an interface that contains a single method **Enumerator GetEnumerator();**. Which makes IEnumerable **read-only**.

Use **ICollection** to Add item in a collections.

Check if you import this namespaces:

**System.Collections.Generic;**

**System.Linq;**